# Make div in the middle fill remaining space

Tags: html, css

I have this HTML structure (Simplified). I want to make it so that the logo, `input` and `button` are:

1) Vertically aligned in the header

2) The logo and button has a fixed size. I want the `input` in the middle of those two items to be the remaining `width` between them.

(Logo to the left, `button` to the right. `Input` then the width of the in between bit)

Then when the window is resized, the `input` text auto resizes.

```
<div class="header">
    <div id="logo">Logo here</div>
    <input type="text"/>
    <div class="button>Button title</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Having you explored `flex-box` solutions? If you are not worried about compatibility for legacy browsers this will be the most efficient approach, let the browser do all the calculations. **flex - CSS | MDN:** https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex

Answer (score 2, accepted):

using flexbox you can do that,

- apply `display: flex;` to the parent (`.header`) so the whole container is now a flex  element
- use `align-items:center` in parent (`.header`) to vertically align them, see more about [align-items](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/align-items)
- apply `flex:1`(shorthanded for `flex-grow:1` `flex-shrink:1` `flex-basis:0`)  to `input` to grow the remaining space left

```css
.header {
  display: flex;
 /* justify-content: space-between; */  /* this is optional, because input{flex:1} is doing its job */
  align-items:center;
  /*demo*/
  border:1px solid red;
  height:60px;
}

input {
  flex: 1;
  /*demo*/
  margin: 0 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
  <div id="logo">Logo here</div>
  <input type="text" />
  <div class="button">Button title</div>
</div>
```